# Should I send [locationManager stopUpdatingLocation] in locationManager:didFailWithError:?

Tags: cocoa-touch, core-location

My app uses the typical pattern of starting a CLLocationManager and then calling `stopUpdatingLocation` from `locationManager:didUpdateToLocation:fromLocation:` if the `newLocation` is accurate enough. My question is whether I also need to call

```
[locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
```

in `locationManager:didFailWithError:`. The Apple docs say

> If the location service is unable to retrieve a location right away, it reports a `kCLErrorLocationUnknown` error and keeps trying. In such a situation, you can simply ignore the error and wait for a new event.
>
> If the user denies your application’s use of the location service, this method reports a `kCLErrorDenied` error. Upon receiving such an error, you should stop the location service.

In the former case I shouldn’t call `stopUpdatingLocation`, since the location manager may still emit a good location. What about the other cases? My app always checks `[CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled]` and `[CLLocationManager authorizationStatus]` before trying to use location services, so do I really need to handle the `kCLErrorDenied` case? And in the event of any other error, will location services be stopped automatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off I think you should handle most error cases. Especially if it's as easy to handle as this one. ;-)
What happens if the user has granted access and uses your app. While the app is running she multitasks and changes into settings.app to disable location services; either generally or specifically for your app. Then you already checked for authorization and use location updates, but suddenly you aren't authorized anymore. I guess that's exactly the case you are asking about, right?